# How can I get jQueryUI button icons to be rendered when the buttons are hidden on page initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using DataTables to build a basic grid for listing products that can be ordered. One of the columns in the table includes an "Add" button with a jQuery cart icon. The icons are rendered on the buttons only on the first page of the DataTable output. When I page through the DataTable, the icons are not rendered on the buttons. How can I get the icons to render on the buttons on the hidden pages?

Comment: It might be best to see how you're initializing your DataTables. If you're creating the buttons in HTML, you can also add classes tht will create the look and feel you want without initializing via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Been awhile since I used datatables but you need to listen the the event when the page is loaded and than you can init your buttons

```
var table = $('#YourTable')

table.on('page.dt', function () {
  table.find('button').button()
});
```

Comment: Tried playing around with this, but, couldn't get it to work.... Will keep fiddling...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS for Button styling in jQuery UI. Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th style="width: 25px;">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" title="Add"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Hope that helps.